# How to take the connected Wifi SSID

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi

I need to take SSID of connected WiFi and first i tried this:

```
val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
val wifiInfo = wifiManager.connectionInfo
textField.text = wifiInfo.ssid
```

But `wifiInfo.ssid` returns `<unknown ssid>` when testing on emulator with API 30 or Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro(Android 11), just as in emulator with API 27 `wifiInfo.ssid` returns correct SSID.

Then i tried this:

```
val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .build()
val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
        //wifiInfo = networkCapabilities.transportInfo as WifiInfo
        Log.d("%%%", "onCapabilitiesChanged: ${networkCapabilities.transportInfo}")
    }
}
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)
connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, networkCallback)
```

But `networkCapabilities.transportInfo` always `null`

EDIT:

Permissions in **manifest** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

Request location permission in `OnCreate()`:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)
```

And it successfully granted.

SOLVE 1:

I just forget to on `Geolocation` on my phone)
It solves problem while i using first method taking wifiinfi by `wifiManager.connectionInfo` but when i use second one by `networkCapabilities.transportInfo` it still returns `null`, and since first method is `Deprecated in java` maybe it is not good to use it.

Then, I would be glad to have your comments about the second method.

Comment: have you done permissions? usually null means you dont have permissions

Answer (score 0):

Google assumes that knowing ssid means knowing location.

Go for fine location permission and you will see.